# Autofill with AJAX and Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html-parsing

I'm trying to create an autofill script with AJAX and the Simple HTML DOM Parser. Here's what I have so far:

The PHP file (discogs.php):

```
<?php

    ini_set('user_agent', 'TEST/1.0 +http://127.0.0.1/test/');

    require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    // Create DOM from URL
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.discogs.com/release/'.$_POST["album_id"]);

    // Grab the Label
    $label = $html->find('.content > a', 0);
    echo $label;

    // Grab the Catalogue Number
    $catno = $html->find('.content', 0);
    echo $catno;

    // Grab the tracklist
    $tracklist = $html->find('div#tracklist', 0);     
    echo $tracklist; 

?>
```

To save space I've put the HTML and jQuery here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mobius1/cYGWs/

I know how to fill a single textarea/input by using  `$('element').val(data)`, but I can't figure out how to fill all three inputs with the three variables from the PHP file (`$label`, `$catno` and `$tracklist`).

Is it possible?

Comment: By the way, why don't you use [Discogs API](http://www.discogs.com/developers/) instead of parsing DOM? You need the PHP tunneling as well, but it's all up to the client then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make change into script as below

```
 jQuery.post('discogs.php', jQuery("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {

 $('element').val(data);

                 },"json");
```

Then, change your php script as below & remove you echo variable statement

```
// New line of code for json
ini_set('user_agent', 'TEST/1.0 +http://127.0.0.1/test/');
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    // Create DOM from URL
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.discogs.com/release/3894873');

     // Grab the Label
     $label = $html->find('.content > a', 0);

    // Grab the Catalogue Number
    $catno = $html->find('.content', 0);

    // Grab the tracklist
    $tracklist = $html->find('div#tracklist', 0); 


$data =  array (
 "label" => (string) $label,
 "catno" => (string) $catno,
  "tracklist" => (string) $tracklist,
);

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Then, change your success handler function as below

```
function(data) {

 $('lable element id').val(data.label);
 $('catno element id').val(data.catno);
 $('tracklist element id').val(data.tracklist);

                 }
```

Comment: Okay, I've completed all the edits, but the inputs all have `[object Object]` in them after running.

Comment: code seems perfect. can you run your discogs.php file directly with static album id and tell what result you get ? i just made test script and running fine

Comment: Hmm, same thing. Apache error log shows this warning: `[Sat Sep 22 19:52:58 2012] [error] PHP Warning:  json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: recursion detected in /test/discogs.php on line 25, referer: http://127.0.0.1/test/index.html`

Comment: I forgot to say that the above occurs in a live environment, when runnning it locally with xampp, the inputs remain blank after running the script. The apache error logs in xampp give the same warning as above.

Comment: it seems php json_encode not enabled. let's try another way. see my updated answer

Comment: Nothing is happening. No errors or warnings. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Thanks, but i really like to know what values you are getting into $label,$catno,$tracklist in php ? can you paste it ? last try

Comment: Do you mean what should be in the inputs after the script runs?

Comment: No, what you getting in discogs.php for all above variables ?

Comment: Nothing. For some reason when I run it locally with xampp, it crashes apache. When running it live on my server, nothing happens.

Comment: before adding json in your php, all variable was have some values ?

Comment: Before you edited your original code, all inputs were filled with `[object Object]` and there were php warnings after I hit the submit button. When json was added, nothing happens, the inputs remain blank.

Comment: php warnings are really bug of php. here you can read it http://noteslog.com/post/detecting-recursive-dependencies-in-php-composite-values/

Comment: I have solution but i want see what values of label, catno, tracklist you are getting from http://www.discogs.com this site

Comment: oh.. you are getting html tags with value also with quotes that is causing problem.you need to get real values from those tags

Comment: Yeah, this is what is supposed to be in the inputs, but they remain blank.